Fedora installation / Restore Timeshift snapshot from LiveUSB
When I used Ubuntu, in grub i had "Rescue Mode" which I could use to restore timeshift snapshots in case I break the system and the OS refuses to load.
Now I use Fedora 40, but I've no such option; so how can I use the liveUSB to restore snapshots of Timeshift in case i break the installation... Help on information is appreciated!!

Fedora 40 still has rescue mode: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f40/system-administrators-guide/kernel-module-driver-configuration/Working_with_the_GRUB_2_Boot_Loader/#sec-Booting_to_Rescue_Mode
